# Not getting Expected Output while retrieving difference of the 2 records

Tags: java, linux

**Problem**

I have file1 having 20,000 numbers in one file and file2 having 9997 numbers in another file.
I want the Numbers which are not there in file2 i.e those 10,003 numbers

Solution

I have created 3 HashMap.

1)First HashMap stores the records of first file,second HashMap stores the records of second file,third HashMap stores the records of difference of the records of the file.

2)I Applied contains method to search file2 record in file1.If file1 record doesn't exist,i put in third hashmap.

```
public class ReadFromFile {
static HashMap hm=null;
static HashMap hm1=null;
static HashMap hm2=null;

private static final String FILENAME = "/home/jalaj/Download/PrimaryBase";
private static final String FILENAME1 = "/home/jalaj/Downloads/logsBase";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    hm2=new HashMap<>();
    int count=0;
     hm=readFromFile(FILENAME);

     hm1=readFromFile(FILENAME1);
     Set s=hm.keySet();
     Iterator it=s.iterator();
     while(it.hasNext()){    
         String me=(String)(it.next());
if(!(hm1.containsKey(me))){
             hm2.put(me,0);
             count++;
         }   
     }  
     System.out.println(count);
 }

 public static HashMap readFromFile(String FILENAME){
    int count=0; 
    hm=new HashMap();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;

    try {

        fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            hm.put(sCurrentLine, 0);
            count++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            if (br != null)
                br.close();

            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
    System.out.println(count);
    return hm;
}

}
```

Output getting

20000

9997

0

Expected Output

20000

9997

10,003

Comment: What does "my sql error 995 occured even after Server Restart" have to do with this code and expected output?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis By mistake Updated the recorsds.

Comment: Your code could be massively shortened and simplified using typed collections, try-with-resource, and for-each loops.

Comment: Also, why don't you use `size()` function of hasmap?
It's easier than having a variable that stores how many entrys each map has.

Comment: Also, no need to use a `HashMap` if you are mapping everything to 0. Just use a `HashSet`.

Comment: **HINT**: In your `readFromFile` method, ask yourself which `HashMap` you are adding things to.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Agreed, although that's exactly what `HashSet` does, internally. Also: Good spot, why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @tobias_k I would, but I really have to get to bed. Feel free to post.

Comment: @tobias_k I will optimize it later but I need this brute force technique to work.I want to know why the output is wrong

Comment: @JalajChawla This is not about (premature) optimization, but about readable code. And in general, readable code is much easier to debug and generally to "get to work" than ugly code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code. In `readFromFile(String name)` you redeclare `hm` attribute as `hm= new HashMap()` and after initialization, you return it. That causes that both of `hm` and `hm1` has same values, and so, `hm2` stores no differences.

Change this line `hm= new HashMap();` to this one `HashMap hm= new HashMap();` e volià.

**PD:** Also, you should use `size()` instead of a count variable, and use a `HashSet` as Michael Markidis suggests.

*EDIT*: I realized same thing as Michael Markidis before reading his comment, so grand mind Michael Markidis!

Comment: I would have said to not even have those static variables for the hashmaps. Shadowing statics. Yikes!!

Comment: In fact, this code needs a good refactor. `private` fields, use parametizered `HashSet`...

Answer (score 0):

I assume the numbers in file1 and file2 are unique. If that is the case the code needs modification in logic as well as the verbosity is concerned. I have refactored it as:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFromFile {

    private static final String FILENAME = "/home/jalaj/Download/PrimaryBase";
    private static final String FILENAME1 = "/home/jalaj/Downloads/logsBase";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> firstList = readFromFile(FILENAME);
        ArrayList<Integer> secondList = readFromFile(FILENAME1);
        ArrayList<Integer> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Integer number : firstList) {
            if(!secondList.contains(number)) {
                outputList.add(number);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(outputList.size());
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> readFromFile(String FILENAME){
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            String sCurrentLine;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.trim()));
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(list.size());
        return list;
    }
}
```

This code should produce the expected output.

Comment: While this code may produce the expected output and is cleaner looking: 1) This doesn't address what the issue is, 2) Using an ArrayList makes this far less efficient than using a Map. Worst case scenario, you have added (20000 * 9997) -  20000 more steps.